# Downloading Google Chrome using Powershell

Tags: google-chrome, powershell, installation, script

Is it possible to download the latest version of Google Chrome using Powershell. I'm an IT Admin looking at putting a script together for our field techs. Since upgrading our client machines to Windows 10 21H2 LTSC, the current script no longer works which used to download the .msi and install it. Seems Google has changed the way it now downloads and installs.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? What was your old script? What part(s) of it have stopped working?

Comment: winget is an option, chocolatery is an option, and even `Invoke-WebRequest -uri $URL -OutFile $SaveAs` if you know the address. For invoke-webrequest to work, ensure that your script has SSL 1.2 enabled. `$TLS12Protocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType] 'Ssl3 , Tls12'` `[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $TLS12Protocol`

Answer (score 13):

With [winget](https://winget.run/pkg/Google/Chrome):

```
winget install -e --id Google.Chrome
```

It is a Windows package manager from Microsoft and part of the App Installer https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9NBLGGH4NNS1

Install via

```
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.WinGet.Client
```

Read more at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/

Comment: prefer not to install "extra" tools to get the apps downloaded. Google should just make the msi downloadable.

Comment: Do you consider the web browser to download the msi an extra tool? In Linux, a package manager is essential: apt on Debian and Ubuntu, pacman on Arch, Zypper on openSUSE and yum on RHEL. Windows puts a lot of effort into winget to get on par. I encourage you to give it a try.

Comment: no cachius, the browser is not an "extra" tool - powershell should be able to download and install msi all in one go.

Answer (score 4):

Without you telling us what is actually going wrong, giving you the right answer is going to be hard.

Yes, I can name a few different ways on how to install Chrome, but I suspect the problem you're having is not so much the url changing, but the fact that SSL/TLS1.2 is forced and older versions are disabled. If you don't enable this in your script, all the various download options will simply not connect, and thus not work.

Put the following in your script before you initiate the download and if its indeed this, then it should work again.

```
$TLS12Protocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType] 'Ssl3 , Tls12'
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $TLS12Protocol
```

Comment: problem having is not ssl but rather app compatibility. for example when downloading from http://dl.google.com/edgedl/chrome/install/GoogleChromeStandaloneEnterprise64.msi and installing i get an error that the app is not compatible for my current version of windows

Comment: That is crucial information. Please edit your question and include that information to receive answers that help you. Include the target OS version as well.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this website](https://www.snel.com/support/install-chrome-in-windows-server) :

```
$LocalTempDir = $env:TEMP; $ChromeInstaller = "ChromeInstaller.exe"; (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://dl.google.com/chrome/install/375.126/chrome_installer.exe', "$LocalTempDir\$ChromeInstaller"); & "$LocalTempDir\$ChromeInstaller" /silent /install; $Process2Monitor =  "ChromeInstaller"; Do { $ProcessesFound = Get-Process | ?{$Process2Monitor -contains $_.Name} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name; If ($ProcessesFound) { "Still running: $($ProcessesFound -join ', ')" | Write-Host; Start-Sleep -Seconds 2 } else { rm "$LocalTempDir\$ChromeInstaller" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose } } Until (!$ProcessesFound)
```

Tested and working on Windows (10, 11) and Windows Server as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: And do you expect to update this script every time a new version of Chrome comes out?  The download URL in your script has Chrome version in it.

Comment: I'm still looking for ways to detect the latest version number.

Comment: correct - thats the hard part. finding an installer link that always contains the latest version